# Django WSGI and ASGI via Passenger confusion

Tags: django, nginx, wsgi, plesk, asgi

Hi all I have a dedicated plesk server on the internet running debian 12. I've started experimenting with Django and deploying django apps via apache and Nginx. I have successfully managed to get a simple Django app to run via mod_wsgi on apache and also passenger wsgi on both apache and nginx. With mod_wsgi its clear that the Django wsgi.py file in the project is called and the apache directive simply points to that file my first confusion is with passenger and the configuration does it ignore the project wsgi.py settings completely? The second confusion starts with ASGI I thought nginx simply passes the request over to Django and python to handle like it does in WSGI but I can't get it to work I have been trying to find a simple setup for ASGI on a dedicated server but all I get is projects running the local django server. Do I need to configure nginx? should I make a file passenger.asgi.py? there is very little documentation concerning implementing it onto a running server with domains... Any ideas examples or tutorials would be much appreciated....